# Linking of a sphere with a Wilson line

Tags: quantum-field-theory, topological-field-theory, wilson-loop

In the papers such as Ref.[I] and Ref.[II], they have introduced the operator,

$$
U_\alpha (M_{d-2}) = e^{\frac{i\alpha}{g^2}\int_{M_{d-2}}*F} .
$$

They said that the Wilson loop:

$$W_n(\gamma)=e^{in\oint_\gamma A} \ ,$$

is charged under the above operator. For example Ref.[II] claims that:

"
*The Ward identity for this
1-form global symmetry implies that such a charge operator supported on an $S^{d−2}$
linking a
Wilson line is equal to the Wilson line up to a phase,
$U_{g=e^{iα}} (S^{d-2}
)W_n(γ) = e^{iαn}W_n(γ)$*"

My question is, what is the meaning of linking between $S^{d-2}$ and a Wilson loop. I can imagine an $S^1$ linked with another $S^1$. But how can, for example in 4d, an $S^2$ is linked with an $S^1$?

**References:**

[I] "Generalized Global Symmetries" by Gaitto et al (https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.5148  [page 14]).

[II] "Non-Invertible Global Symmetries and Completeness of the Spectrum" by Ben Heidenreich et al. (https://arxiv.org/abs/2104.07036   [page 16])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fact of life: In $d$ a dimensions, a $p$-dimensional closed manifold can link with a $q$ dimensional closed manifold if $p+q+1=d$. (cf. [wiki: linking number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linking_number#Generalizations)) $\newcommand{\S}{\mathbb{S}}\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}$

This fact of life implies that $\S^1$ can link with a closed $(d-2)$-dimensional closed manifold, such as $\S^{d-2}$.

To visualise this in 4 dimensions we can think of the sphere as fibred by circles. Explicitly, let's think of $\mathbb{R}^4$ as $\mathbb{R}^3\times\mathbb{R}_t$, where $\mathbb{R}_t$ is time (or Euclidean time, doesn't matter it is for visualisation purposes only). Then an $\S^2$ in $\R^3\times\R_t$ is an $\S^1$ with time-dependent radius. At $t\to-\infty$ it starts its life as a point, $\S^1_{r=\varepsilon}\subset\R^3\times\{t\to-\infty\}$, then it slowly grows until at $t=0$ is is $\S^1_{r=1}\subset\R^3\times\{t=0\}$ and then it shrinks to zero again at $t\to\infty$, $\S^1_{r=\varepsilon}\subset\R^3\times\{t\to\infty\}$. At any such point, this $\S^1_{r(t)}\subset\R^3\times\{t\}$, can link with another $\color{maroon}{\S^1}$. So, if at $t\to-\infty$ your sphere  starts its life linked with an $\color{maroon}{\S^1}$, it will stay linked until it dies at $t\to\infty$ (cf. figure below)

[image: A sphere with an earring]

Comment: The "if and only if" part requires some explanation. It's not at all obvious that $\pi_q(R^d - M^p)$ is non-trivial.

Comment: Here's a [summary on links without proof with links to proofs](https://knotplot.com/links/sphere.html) (pun intended) that contradicts the "if and only if" assertion in the 1st paragraph. Topology produces odd results sometimes: "two 10-dimensional spheres link up in 12, 13, 14, 15, and 16 dimensions, then unlink in 17 dimensions, link up again in 18, 19, 20, and 21 dimensions."

Comment: A much simpler counterexample: take $d=3$, $p=2$, $q=1$, and the manifolds being a 2-torus and a circle. It's obvious that the torus and the circle can link with each other. Yet $p+q+1\neq d$.

Comment: Of course, thanks for pointing that out! I removed the only if part. The linking spheres are indeed surprising (and the pun appreciated).

Comment: @ɪdɪətstrəʊlə Using the same type of picture can we also say that an $S^2$ can link with an $S^3$? 
We can picture $S^3$ as a sequence of $S^2$ (in $R^3$) of time dependent radius which "starts its life" as point grows to a $S^2$ of some finite radius and again shrinks back to a point.

Comment: @TuhinSubhraMukherjee An $\mathbb{S}^2$ can link with an $\mathbb{S}^3$ in six dimensions.

Comment: Is there a good reference to this topic? I mean instead of using pictures, some concrete mathematical formalism.

Comment: @TuhinSubhraMukherjee Generally, [Alexander duality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_duality) would be a good start. [This](http://www.map.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/High_codimension_links) may also be helpful.